# Is there any way to export game progress made on iPad to the same game on Google Play?

Tags: applications, data-transfer, ios

I used iPad to play Six-Guns & Siegefall. Is there any way to export my progress to the same game on Google Play? I want it because I've played them for a long time

Comment: Oh god, another Daniel. Have you tried signing in to facebook on these apps? That's my workaround to this problem.

Comment: yes dan b, i've tried facebook, but can't solve this problem, which game did u solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the app. Some apps use Facebook or another external server to store everything. Many apps just use the built-in cloud save feature of the device, which cannot be shared between iOS and Android.